# Phonegap on Android: getting Drawables/AppIcons back into Javascript environment for display in "browser"

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, icons, drawable

I'm building an Android based WebApp using PhoneGap, and trying to get the app icons of several currently installed applications back into the Javascript environment for displaying in the "browser".

Getting hold of the icons in the ANdroid layer is no problem. I've done that with code similar to this:

Drawable myNewIcon = myResolveInfoInstance.loadIcon(mycontext.getPackageManager());

... but I'm struggling with working out how to get the icon back into the Javascript callback so that I can place it into the "webpage".

If anyone can give me a tip or two on how to achieve this, it would be very much appreciated. It doesn't seem like it should be too difficult...!?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If these drawables are going to be used purely on the web side of your project then putting them in the assets folder is the best idea. Then they can be accessed via:

```
file:///android_asset/www/images/icon.png
```

for instance.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I've used that in other situations, but it won't work for the problem I am currently faced with. I do not have access to the images at the time creating the APK. I'm obtaining these Drawables / icons at Runtime and need to be able to display them.

Comment: The only idea I've had is to try and convert the drawable/icon into a byte array and return that in a JSON string, and then use Javascript to write the byte array back out as a file to then load into the DOM... but I think that'd be way over the top and might not even work.